# Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to use Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite to rewrite my URL **ndd.dev/interet/index/id/1/** for **ndd.dev/i/rouen/1/** with zend 1.12

For this I have add in my bootstrap :

```
protected function _initRouter () {

    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH.'/config/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
    $router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
    $router->addConfig($config, 'routes');

}
```

into my "application.ini" :

> routes.interet.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
>
> routes.interet.route = "/i/(.+)/([0-9]+)/"
>
> routes.interet.defaults.controller = "interet"
>
> routes.interet.defaults.action = "index"
>
> routes.interet.map.1 = "seo"
>
> routes.interet.map.2 = "id"
>
> routes.interet.reverse ="i/%s/%d/"

my .htaccess :

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
>
> RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
>
> RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

But **www.ndd.dev/i/rouen/1**/ returns :

> Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception Invalid controller specified (i)
>   envoyée dans /www/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php à la ligne 248

have I forgoten smoething like addRoute or something else ?

I've tried this method in my bootstrap:

```
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

    $r = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        "/i/([-\w]+)/(\d+)/",
        array('controller' => 'interet', 'action' => 'index'), 
        array(1 => 'seo', 2 => 'id'),
        'i/%s/%d/'
    );

    $router->addRoute('interet', $r);
```

and same result, he tries to found "i" controler

*Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception Invalid controller specified (i)*

Thanks

Comment: Do you have another route also called 'interet'?

Comment: The problem was the regex : "i/([-\w]+)/(\d+)" instead of "/i/([-\w]+)/(\d+)/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the regex :

```
"i/([-\w]+)/(\d+)"
```

instead of

```
"/i/([-\w]+)/(\d+)/"
```

Comment: yup, it's often something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Typically your application.ini routes will conform to the structure (yours don't, unless you truncated them) :

```
// /application/configs/application.ini
//uri for this route
resources.router.routes.login.route = /login
//module for the route, 'default' is used if there is no named module
resources.router.routes.login.defaults.module = default
//default controlle for this route
resources.router.routes.login.defaults.controller = auth
//default action for this route
resources.router.routes.login.defaults.action = login
```

note how each line starts with ***resource*** and the fourth word is the ***"name"*** of the route (in this case it's *'login'*).

I'm not 100% sure but I don't think your bootstrap `_initRouter()` is helping you here, I don't remember needing this when the routes are defined in the `application.ini`. Maybe comment it out and see if it helps.

Comment: hmm nothing... he tries to found "i" controler instead of to use the route... _Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception Invalid controller specified (i)_

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this method in my bootstrap:

```
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

    $r = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        "/i/([-\w]+)/(\d+)/",
        array('controller' => 'interet', 'action' => 'index'), 
        array(1 => 'seo', 2 => 'id'),
        'i/%s/%d/'
    );

    $router->addRoute('interet', $r);
```

and same result, he tries to found "i" controler

*Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception Invalid controller specified (i)*